# Why is this method returning -858993460

Tags: c++, pointers

The printResults() method below (called from the main method at the bottom) returns -858993460 for all four values. Why is this? I have confirmed with cout statements that the numbers and calculations are correct within the doCalc() method, so I'm assuming the error is in the way I'm using pointers and calling the printResults() method...

```
typedef int matrix[2][2] ;

struct matrices {
matrix a;
matrix b;
};

...getInput() method constructs 

matrix* doCalc (matrices m){
matrix toReturn;
char input;
cout << "Which calculation would you like to perform - (M)ultiply, (A)dd, (S)ubtract?";
cin >> input;
switch(input){
case 'M':
    toReturn[0][0] = ((m.a[0][0])*(m.b[0][0]));
    cout << "XX " << ((m.a[0][0])*(m.b[0][0]));
    toReturn[0][1] = (m.a[0][1]*m.b[0][1]);
    cout << "YY " <<  (m.a[0][1]*m.b[0][1]);
    toReturn[1][0] = (m.a[1][0]*m.b[1][0]);
    toReturn[1][1] = (m.a[1][1]*m.b[1][1]);
    break;
case 'A':
    toReturn[0][0] = (m.a[0][0]+m.b[0][0]);
    toReturn[0][1] = (m.a[0][1]+m.b[0][1]);
    toReturn[1][0] = (m.a[1][0]+m.b[1][0]);
    toReturn[1][1] = (m.a[1][1]+m.b[1][1]);
    break;
case 'S':
    toReturn[0][0] = (m.a[0][0]-m.b[0][0]);
    toReturn[0][1] = (m.a[0][1]-m.b[0][1]);
    toReturn[1][0] = (m.a[1][0]-m.b[1][0]);
    toReturn[1][1] = (m.a[1][1]-m.b[1][1]);
    break;
}
return &toReturn;

}

void printResult(matrix m){
cout<<"---RESULT---\n";
cout << m[0][0] << "  " << m[0][1] << "\n";
cout << m[1][0] << "  " << m[1][1] << "\n";

}

void main() {
matrices m = getInput();
cout << m.a[0][0] << "  " << m.a[0][1] << "\n";
cout << m.a[1][0] << "  " << m.a[1][1] << "\n\n";
cout << m.b[0][0] << "  " << m.b[0][1] << "\n";
cout << m.b[1][0] << "  " << m.b[1][1] << "\n";

matrix* calc = doCalc(m);
matrix c = &calc;

printResult(*calc);

}
```

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a local variable. Once the function returns that variable no longer exists.

Comment: `void main` is non-standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the matrix `toReturn` will be destroyed when the function exits, you will need to use some form of persistent memory allocation (look up *new* and *delete*). As such all the values are just nonsense.

Comment: It should be new in C++ not malloc.

Comment: Look up `new` and `delete` if you must or maybe return by value instead.

Comment: By value is best here. In second place comes a smart pointer, as it's clear to the caller that they now own the memory, and it will be freed regardless of whether they do so manually or not.

Comment: @smitec  I would call malloc inside the doCalc() method, or in the main method?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious But how can I return an array by value in C?

Comment: @user2356560 `std::vector` works pretty well for C++. For C I would retag the question.

Comment: @Borgleader oh yes sorry I was thinking C by default.

Comment: Here's your rep back :)

Answer (score 0):

`matrix toReturn;` is a local variable, allocated on the stack.  After `doCalc` returns, its contents are undefined.  In this case, the memory at its old address gets overwritten with random garbage.

Answer (score 0):

`toReturn` will be destroyed with the stack frame when `doCalc` is finished.

Instead of returning the pointer pass it to the function you are calling.

```
void doCalc (matrices m, matrix* pReturnMatrix)

matrix* calc = new matrix();
doCalc(m, calc);
```

Answer (score 0):

`toReturn` is a local variable in the `doCalc` function. It will no longer exist when the function returns.

An easy way to fix this is to pass a reference to the matrix that will store the result:

```
matrix* doCalc (matrices m, matrix& toReturn ){
```

Then remove this line from `doCalc`:

```
matrix toReturn;
```

And change how the function is called from this:

```
matrix* calc = doCalc(m);
matrix* calc = doCalc(m);
matrix c = &calc;

printResult(*calc);
```

To this:

```
matrix calc;
doCalc(m,calc);
printResult(calc);
```

There are other ways to fix this, e.g. new/delete as suggested in other places. However, now we will go into who allocates and who owns the memory. It won't be clear from the function signature alone who is responsible for what.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid managing dynamically allocated memory and requiring the caller supply an lvalue if you return by value.

```
matrix doCalc (const matrices& m)
{
    matrix toReturn;

    // Code here

    return toReturn;
}
```

You can assign the results to a `matrix` object or use it in an expression like below.

```
if(doCalc(m).a[0][0] == 1)
{
     // do something
}
```

or

```
matrix mat(doCalc(m));
if(mat.a[0][0] == 1)
{
     // do something
}
```